# ExecuteScalar - Specific Column

Tags: sql, asp.net, executescalar

my plans table has 15 fields, using ExecuteScalar seems to grab the result from the first column only, how do I specify the column name that I want? for example when I run the code below, it will return 1 which is the value in my ID column, but I want `plan_rate` column.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CustomerDataConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
   conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[plans] WHERE age_group = @age_group AND coverage_type = @coverage_type", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age_group", dd_ageGroup.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@coverage_type", dd_coverageType.Text);

    Object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if (result != null)
        Label1.Text = "Plan rate: $" + result.ToString();

    else
        Label1.Text = "Plan is not available in this state.";


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First line in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

If you want just `plan_rate` you can change your query to:

`"SELECT plan_rate FROM [dbo].[plans]...`

or use `ExecuteReader` and read the column you want from the `DataReader`.

```
using(DataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        ...
        string plan_rate = reader["plan_rate"].ToString();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If you will place the `reader` into a `using` block, I will upvote.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Did so, and fixed a typo as well.

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteScaler` can only be used when your return one single value. It means your query needs to be one column and one row only.

So you need to change your `Select * from` with a `Select myColumn from` .

If you need second fastest execution and return more than one column you can use `ExecuteReader`.

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read()){
   Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));//reader[0] column1, reader[1] column2,..
}
```

Comment: What would you recommend me to use? What is the best way to re-write the above code to accomplish the columns names, I do not want to write 10 ExecuteScalar codes for each column. Thank you sir.

Comment: Well, you _can_ use it when returning multiple columns/rows, but it will only return the value from the first column and first row.

Comment: @user3345212 you can use `ExecuteReader`

Comment: Object result = cmd.ExecuteReader(); is giving me an error

Comment: @user3345212 I just provided a sample it returns a `SqlDataReader` object